# In my WordPress multisite, The Events Calendar works on one site, but another shows no upcoming events

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor, multisite

We're currently in the process of redeveloping a bunch of radio station websites and decided to go with a multisite installation to try to keep things more uniform from site to site, common plugins, single user accounts/passwords for multiple sites, etc.

I added and network-activated Tribe's The Events Calendar. It works like a charm on the first site.

After a delay of a few months, we're finally back to developing the next couple of sites, but on one of them, none of the events are showing up, at all. After adding the event, when you try to view it on the front end, you get the 404 page. The main `/events/` archive page and the `/events/category/concerts/` pages display "There are no upcoming events."

The sites are using the same Elementor Hello Child Master theme, with a kit that was exported from the first and imported into the new ones.

I'm on a server with PHP 8.2, latest versions of WordPress and all of my plugins. Events still work fine on the first site I made doing this, and I can't figure out any reason why they wouldn't be on the new ones. Has anyone run into something similar and found a solution?

So far I've tried:

- clearing redis, site, and browser caches
- re-confirming my pretty permalinks
- network-disabling the plugins I thought most likely to be causing the issues (Elementor and Elementor Pro, Wordfence, WP Rocket, etc)
- switching to Twenty Twenty (one article I read from a while ago said the plugin wasn't fully compatible with full-site editing yet - this may no longer be the case)
- disabling EVERY plugin except The Events Calendar on the new site
- deleting and recreating events and event categories
- I found one article that said that there wasn't a site_url option set, but that's also not the case

Nothing is working. Still 404s on individual events, and still "There are no upcoming events" on the Events archive pages/category pages. I enabled logging on the Events Calendar plugin, but the logs are empty.

The *only* thing I can think that might be causing the issue is with the export/import of the Elementor kit from the first site to the new one, but I don't know how to get around that, either. Any suggestions of tactics I can try would be appreciated.

**edit**
It *is* working on one of the two other sites, but not on one, which makes me think even more strongly that it's some setting that got screwed up somewhere when we imported the Elementor kit.

If I were to uninstall/reinstall the plugin, would *all* of the settings get removed so that I can start fresh, or would there be lingering settings in the database somewhere?